# trouble to send mail from XAMPP servver

Tags: php, email

I have been trying so many times to send mail from xampp, for that I set all things which is required but still mail function is not working.

**I have tried with the following steps:**

1. Remove `;` from `php.ini` file where `extension=php_openssl.dll`
2. [mail function]

   ```
   SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
   smtp_port=587
   sendmail_from = shail.gandhi132@gmail.com
   sendmail_path = "\"c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
   ```
3. C:\xampp\sendmail

   [sendmail]

   ```
   smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
   smtp_port=587
   error_logfile=error.log
   debug_logfile=debug.log
   auth_username=shail.gandhi132@gmail.com
   auth_password=(My passowd)
   force_sender=shail.gandhi132@gmail.com
   ```
4. And My PHP code is

   ```
    $to = 'sgandhi132@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'This is subject';
    $message = 'This is HTML message';
    $header ='From:shail.gandhi132@gmail.com';
    $send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    if($send == true) 
    {echo "Mail Sent";}
    else 
    { echo "Error";}
   ```

Comment: Have you checked the log ?

Comment: Improve Formatting

Comment: how to check log ??? ( I am fresher programmer )